# this is null in directive with es6

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm writing directive with es6 (and compiling it with babel) after class constructor angular calls the link function of the directive but for some reason the `this` is null.

Code snippet:

```
class AutoSaveDirective {
    constructor($timeout) {
        this.restrict = 'EA';
        this.require = '^form';

        this.$timeout = $timeout;
        this.scope = {
            autoOnSave: '&',
            autoSaveDebounce: '='
        }
    }

    link(scope, el, attr, formCtrl) {
        scope.$watch(()=> {
            console.log('form changed, starting timout');
            if (!formCtrl.$dirty) {
                return;
            }

at this line ==>if(this.currentTimeout){
                console.log('old timeout exist cleaning');
                this.currentTimeout.cancel();
                this.currentTimeout = null;
            }

            console.log('starting new timeout');
            this.currentTimeout = $timeout(()=>{
                console.log('timeout reached, initiating onsave')
                scope.autoOnSave();
            }, scope.autoSaveDebounce);
        });
    }
}

angular.module('sspApp').directive('autoSave', () => new AutoSaveDirective());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to bind your link function to the class due the the way that angular calls it.

```
class AutoSaveDirective {
    constructor($timeout) {
        //...

        this.link = this.unboundLink.bind(this);
    }

    unboundLink(scope, el, attr, formCtrl) {
        scope.$watch(()=> {
            //...
        });
    }
}
```

If you want to use classes with angular a better approach would be to use them for controllers and use the controllerAs syntax. e.g.

```
angular.module('sspApp').directive('autoSave', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            autoOnSave: '&',
            autoSaveDebounce: '=',
            formCtrl: '='
        },
        bindToController: true,
        controller: AutoSave,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    };
});

class AutoSave {
    constructor() {
        //Move logic from link function in here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `link` function is returned by the `compile` function and it's called as a function, not as a method. So you can define a `compile` instead of a `link` method:

```
compile() {
  return (scope, el, attr, formCtrl)  => { ... };
}
```

Having said that, there's no value in defining a directive as a class.